# Is set Dedekind continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, continuity, real-numbers

The set is called Dedekind continuous when there is no way to make a $A||A'$ or $A)(A'$ cuts where:

- $A||A'$ cut means there is the biggest element in $A$ set and the lowest element in $A'$ set
- $A)(A'$ cut means there is no biggest element in $A$ and no lowest element in $A'$

We all know that $\mathbb{R}$ is Dedekind continuous.

The question is whether the following subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is Dedekind continuous or not:

$$ M = (-\infty; 2) \cup [3; +\infty) $$

It is obvious this set can't be "geometry" continuous since there is a gap between $2$ and $3$ but I can't find a way to make $A||A'$ or $A)(A'$ cuts to prove it is not Dedekind continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set is Dedekind continuous.

> It is obvious this set can't be "geometry" continuous since there is a gap between 2 and 3...

At first glance, the fact this set is Dedekind continuous actually sounds weird. There is "gap" between $2$ and $3$. How this could be considered continuous in any way!?

[image: Imaginary gap]

But this is not what actually happens. The set $ [3; +\infty)$ comes **right after** the $(-\infty; 2)$ so there is no gap between them.  The true image would be:

[image: True image]

As you can clearly see, moving from the left to right we **gradually** and **continously** move from *elements* infinitely close to $3$ right to *element* $3$ without any "jumping the gaps".

Dedekinds cuts can be applied to any totally ordered sets (including sets of numbers). So the imaginary "gape" is just a kind of a mind trick which occurs because we think of these sets as bunches of numbers that represent a cetrain value rather then thinking of them as sets of **impersonal ordered elements** or even dots.

If we name $3$ as "element $b$" the pharse "gradually move from elements that lie to left of $b$ to element $b$ itself" does not sound weird at all.

Heading back to "geometric continuity". Imagine we cut a $[\ldots)$ section of a straight line. We can easily glue it, so it won't lose its "geometric continuity".

---

The following sets are Dedekind continuous as well:

- $ (-\infty; 1) \cup [5; +\infty) $
- $ [2; 11] \cup (54; 108) $
- $\cdots$

---

It is also worth mentioning that the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are not Dedekind continuous:

- $ (-\infty; 2] \cup [3; +\infty) $ since we can make $A||A'$ cut
- $ (-\infty; 1) \cup (5; +\infty) $ since we can make $A)(A'$ cut
- $\ldots$

Comment: Nice diagrams. Our intuitive extrinsic view of $M$ (seing $M$ first and foremost as a subset of a bigger set $\Bbb R$) is what makes this result seem counterintuitive. "Forgetting" that $\Bbb R$ exists outside $M$, and just seing $M$ for what it is, like you do here, is one way to resolve this.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you. I am just starting leraning calculus and I really needed a somewhat demonstrative explanation of why it is still continuous in the way most of us think of something "geometrically continuous". As far as I know these refers to geometry and lack of formal arithmetic number theory in calculus at the end of eighteens are the main reasons that led Dedekind to create a formal definition of set continuity.

Answer (score 4):

This set is Dedekind continuous. In fact, it is order isomorphic to the real line through the following map:
$$
f: M\to \Bbb R\\
f(x) = \cases{x & if $x<2$\\
x-1 & if $x \geq 3$}
$$

Comment: This is kind of sad. I though Dedekind wanted to create a formal definition for continuous sets which would be close to "geometric" continuity. And this example shows that Dedekind continuous set can be far from what we think of something continuous...

Comment: @CMTV: Indeed, the order topology on the subset is not the same as the subset topology (the set $[3,\infty)$ is an open set in the subset topology, preventing the set from being topologically connected, but it is not an open set in the order topology on the subset, under which the full set is indeed homeomorphic to the real line). Thus the order is indeed insufficient to describe geometric continuity. One could say that the order “glues together“ any parts that fit together.

Comment: @CMTV It is as close as one can get when all the structure we have on $M$ is the order. Once we get something more (in particular something geometric, like a topology or a metric), then we can say more. But until then, the notion of Dedekind continuity is all we have to work with, and Dedekind continuity _only_ cares about order, and as far as order is concerned, $M$ is essentially the same as $\Bbb R$.